# Moving Webmail to Google Apps

Tags: gmail, email, migrate-data, webmail

I am using Webmail (RoundCube) on cPanelX, using BlueHost web hosting.

I am planning to move to Google Apps, is there any way to move my existing mail to Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

BlueHost already have a Knowledgebase Article about [How to access your e-mail with Gmail](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/gmailpop). You can skip the Outgoing Mail (SMTP) section as you presumably won't be using their service to send mail any more.

These are basically the instructions for using Google's [Mail Fetcher](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289) to pull in old email, but they include BlueHost-specific settings. BlueHost had decent screenshots with their instructions, but for completeness they're as follow:

1. Login to your Gmail Account.
2. Choose **Settings**, from the Settings cog.
3. Click **Accounts and Import**.
4. Click '**Add a POP3 mail account you own**".
5. Enter your **Email address**.
6. Click the **Next** button.
7. Enter your full email address as the **Username**.
8. Enter **Password** for your email account.
9. Enter the POP Server. This will be your domain name proceeded by
   "**mail.**"
10. Choose any additional options you may want
11. Click the **Add Account** button.

Answer (score 1):

Since RoundCube supports IMAP, I searched for some solutions to migrate emails to Google using IMAP, and I did find [imapsync](https://fedorahosted.org/imapsync/). There are [some steps available](http://www.joshualyman.com/2011/05/migrating-from-private-imap-to-google-apps-email/) to guide you through (though it is mainly tailored for Linux users.

If it is not feasible for you, you can read more about [migrating to Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57920) to see if any of these fits you.

Comment: I have found a better way, by using the in-built Account Import option in Gmail.